# WCF Generic result class always is empty

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have this generic class for my server responses:

```
[DataContract]
    public class GenericResult<T>
    {
        public List<T> ListResult { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
```

and this GetAllBrandsTest method to return data to the client:

```
public async Task<GenericResult<Brand>> GetAllBrandsTest()
        {
            var result = await repo.GetAllAsync<Brand>();
            return new GenericResult<Brand>()
            {
                ListResult = result.ToList(),
                Message = "Success"
            };
        }
```

Everything is OK with this methods counterpart GetAllBrands:

```
public async Task<IList<Brand>> GetAllBrands()
        {            
            return await repo.GetAllAsync<Brand>();
        }
```

But when I call GetAllBrandsTest the result is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Brand))]
public class GenericResult<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Brand> ListResult { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Brand Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Any data type transferred between the server-side and the client-side should be explicitly specified how we serialize and deserialize it. Please use the `DataContract` attribute to specify the data structure the way how to serialize to XML so that the serialization and deserialization can work properly between the service-side and client-side. In addition, for unknown data types, please use the `KnownType` feature to specify the serialization method in advance.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CircleType))]
[KnownType(typeof(TriangleType))]
public class CompanyLogo2

    [DataMember]
    private Shape ShapeOfLogo;
    [DataMember]
    private int ColorOfLogo;
}
[DataContract]
public class Shape { }

[DataContract(Name = "Circle")]
public class CircleType : Shape { }

[DataContract(Name = "Triangle")]
public class TriangleType : Shape { }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types
We either decorate the class with both `DataContract` attribute and `DataMember` attribute or remove the `DataContract` attribute and `DataMember` attribute. Because the `DataContract` serializer will be used by default when the complex data type is without specifying any XML serializer.

Comment: Thank you very much I forgot to decorate it by DataMember.